# How to view the public origin IP of requests coming into an Azure AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

For an Azure AKS cluster that has a Standard Load Balancer how can I view the origin IP addresses for inbound requests?

I am trying to diagnose a potential DDoS on our system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure standard LB doesn't provide access logs. See available metrics [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-diagnostics) You need to get access logs either from your Ingress Controller (if any) or directly from your app's web front-end (Apache, NGINX access logs).